# C++: How to use boost::synchronized_value with boost::synchronize?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to synchronize 2 `boost::synchronized_value` without potential dead-lock and I'm trying to do this:

```
boost::synchronized_value<int> val1;
boost::synchronized_value<int> val2;

auto tuple = boost::synchronize(val1, val2);
```

but this results in this compiler error:

```
error: use of deleted function 'boost::mutex::mutex(const boost::mutex&)'
```

my snippet is not far off the last example provided in [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html#thread.sds.synchronized_valuesxxx.tutorial.operations_across_multiple_objects), so I cannot explain it to myself.

Comment: Do you compile with c++11 or higher, it seems you do a copy whereas it should be a move.

Comment: @Jarod42 MSVC++, C++17. Im not sure why it is not a move, i tried using a rvalue reference to it but it gave me the same result.

Comment: Seems to works as expected [here](http://rextester.com/MVNC33947) (Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64).

Comment: @Jarod42 quite strange trying the exact same code in my IDE results in the same error: http://prntscr.com/jltfi5 (screenshot). I installed boost with vcpkg if that matters.

Comment: @Jarod42 ah ok i tried changing the C++ version to 14 and it compiles fine now but i need version 17 because i want to use structured binding. Is there a way to fix the issue?

Comment: C++17 should even omit the move constructor... Can you try `auto&& tuple = boost::synchronize(val1, val2);` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 nope doesnt work, i allready tried that before.

Comment: It compiles on same site with `g++ -std=c++17`, so it should be a bug of visual.

Comment: anyone else with Visual Studio 2017 should try the code, because it might be that im having a broken install of it and i want to exclude that